# Parse HTML adding ID to all <input>s using NAME in PHP

Tags: php, parsing, dom, html-parsing

I'm trying to take an HTML document in PHP (that I have no control over) and ensuring that each input has an id.  If there's no id then I need to add one using whatever name has been set.

For example:

```
input type="text" name="something" value="something else"
```

I would need to parse this to:

```
input type="text" name="something" id="something" value="something else"
```

I must do this for the entire document.

I have search for a solution but have come up empty handed.

Comment: Are the attributes always in the same order?

Comment: Might have a problem when the names are not unique as ids are suppose to be unique to the page.

Comment: Each of the names are unique.

Comment: @F4r-20 told you it wasnt possible in PHP without complicated HTML parsers! I'l have my vote back now!

Comment: For a bit I I thought maybe I was missing something relatively easy.

Comment: This could be done by `preg_replace_callback`  (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php). Probably ugly, but doable.

Comment: @InGodITrust I've made another answer, I can assure you it wasn't me who downvoted. I don't just downvote if I hear something I don't like.

Answer (score 1):

OK so I completely misunderstood! Answer number 2 here:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument; 
$dom->load('yourdoc.html');// Load document
$inputs = $dom->getElementsByTagName("input"); //Get inputs
for($i=0; $i<$inputs->length; $i++){ // For every input found
    $thisName = $inputs->item($i)->getAttribute("name"); // Put the name in a variable
    $inputs->item($i)->setAttribute("id",$thisName); // Then set ID as the same
}
$dom->save('yourdoc.html'); //Save the document
```

This has to be closer to what you want, surely?

No parsers, just some simple DOM work.

Comment: Thats looking more like it!

Comment: Hey thanks for all of your work on my issue!  I appreciate it!

Comment: Glad to have helped. If the answer worked for you please accept it (:

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do this before the form submission you need to use Javascript.

Using jQuery...

```
$('input').each(function(){
    var name = $(this).attr('name');
    $(this).attr('id','name');
});
```

Comment: Where is jQuery mentioned?

Comment: The OP didn't mention jQuery. The made it relatively clear that they wish for a PHP solution

Comment: @F4r-20 ha ha, that came from his lack of understanding of the difference between a client side language and a server side.

Comment: No I specifically need to parse it on the server side.  I need to load the html in, parse it and then save it back to where ever.  Javascript isn't going to let me do what I need to accomplish but I appreciate the effort.

Comment: @Derek after the form has been submitted?

Comment: No form will not be submitted at all (at least not for this purpose.)  It will merely be parsed as a file and saved.

Answer (score 0):

This could probably be done by `preg_replace_callback` (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php)

Pseudocode:

Use  `preg_replace_callback` to extract  all `<input ... >` and send through `someFunction`

in `someFunction(str)`:

```
If str contains 'id=':
    return str //no need to add id
else:
    extract value of name, insert 'id="name" ' after '<input ' and return str
```